# how to check personal domain user login

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication

What is the way in Java through with I can check if the user is logged in personal domain (google apps domain Ex.example.com) ?

Using gdata, I tried :

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
```

But this returns gmail user only.

For its reference please see [UserServiceFactory](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/UserServiceFactory.html#getUserService%28%29), [User Service](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/UserService.html) & [User](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/User.html).

Also, using gdata, I am getting the login url that is only of gmail login, only.

I also tried the other override method of UserService.createLoginURL :

```
userService.createLoginURL(request.getRequestURI(), "example.com")
```

But, this returns me only gmail login url :(

I suppose, gdata will not solve this problem. Is there any other way ?

Comment: What do you mean "this returns gmail user only"? If someone logs in using a non-gmail.com address, that will return a User object for them just fine.

Comment: No ! If I am login to example.com & not in Gmail. Then it is redirecting me to login page of gmail :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are your Authentication Options in the admin console (in "Application Settings")? Are you using "(Experimental) Federated Login" or "Google Accounts API" ?

In the second case, only Google accounts are accepted... See http://code.google.com/intl/fr/appengine/docs/java/users/overview.html#Authentication_Options for more information.